# Imprimir un número al revés y con espacios

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando realizar un programa que, al ingresar ciertos números, en la salida los dé al revés y separados por un espacio.

Ejemplo:

```
entrada: 0 9 2
 salida: 2 0 9
```

Comment: Hola Marifer , Bienvenida a SOes , muéstrenos cuál es su avance logrado hasta ahora (código), en que tiene problemas así podremos ayudarle mucho mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Al revés sería `2 9 0`, en vez de `2 0 9`... ¿Hay un orden que deba seguir? ¿El orden debe ser aleatorio?

Answer (score 2):

Si los números son únicamente de una cifra, invertirlos es tan sencillo como leer la línea en una cadena, invertir la cadena e imprimir el resultado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string cad;
  std::getline(std::cin,cad);
  std::string cadena_invertida(cad.rbegin(),cad.rend());
  std::cout << cadena_invertida;
}
```

Si, en cambio, los números pueden tener más de una cifra sería recomendable almacenarlos en un contenedor (por ejemlo `std::vector`). Para imprimir los resultados bastaría con recorrer el contenedor desde el final hasta el principio:

```
std::vector<int> numeros;
// Rellenar el vector...

std::for_each(vector.rbegin(),vector.rend(),
              [](int numero){ std::cout << numero << ' '; });
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo mejor es que uses un vector de longitud definida (3 por tu ejemplo) y lo inicialices. Luego lo recorres con un bucle for ascendente para tomar los valores y un bucle for descendente para devolverlos en el orden inverso.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cin>>ent[i];
}
for(int i=2; i>=0; i--)
{
    cout<<ent[i]<<" ";
}
```